# How to customize this automatic slug shortener with an overrwrite function

Tags: admin, slug, pluggable

I am using a slick little piece of code which I have included within my functions file which automatically takes any information entered into the title of a new post and create a slug with specific stop words automatically removed (code included below).

The problem is that sometimes after this slug is automatically created I wanted to click on the slug (under the title) and modify it directly.

My question to the community is... what would I need to change in the code below so that when I click on the slug (under the title) and modify it that whatever I enter there is used without the function below preventing that from happening. Here is the code:

```
// AUTOMATICALLY SANITIZE PAGE/POST SEO SLUG FROM SHORT WORDS
// SOURCE: http://www.vretoolbar.com/news/seo-slugs-wordpress-plugin
   add_filter('name_save_pre', 'seo_slugs', 0);
   function seo_slugs($slug) {
    // We don't want to change an existing slug
 if ($slug) return $slug;
 global $wpdb;
 $seo_slug = strtolower(stripslashes($_POST['post_title']));
 $seo_slug = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $seo_slug); // kill HTML entities
    // kill anything that is not a letter, digit, space or apostrophe
 $seo_slug = preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \']/", "", $seo_slug);
    // Turn it to an array and strip common words by comparing against c.w. array
 $seo_slug_array = array_diff (split(" ", $seo_slug), seo_slugs_stop_words());
    // Turn the sanitized array into a string
 $seo_slug = join("-", $seo_slug_array);
 return $seo_slug;
   }
   function seo_slugs_stop_words () {
   return array ("a", "able", "about", "above", "abroad", "according", "accordingly", "across", "actually", "adj", "after", "afterwards", "again", "against", "ago", "ahead", "ain't", "all", "allow", "allows", "almost", "alone", "along", "alongside", "already", "also", "although", "always", "am", "amid", "amidst", "among", "amongst", "an", "and", "another", "any", "anybody", "anyhow", "anyone", "anything", "anyway", "anyways", "anywhere", "apart", "appear", "appreciate", "appropriate", "are", "aren't", "around", "as", "a's", "aside", "ask", "asking", "associated", "at", "available", "away", "awfully", "b", "back", "backward", "backwards", "be", "became", "because", "become", "becomes", "becoming", "been", "before", "beforehand", "begin", "behind", "being", "believe", "below", "beside", "besides", "best", "better", "between", "beyond", "both", "brief", "but", "by", "c", "came", "can", "cannot", "cant", "can't", "caption", "cause", "causes", "certain", "certainly", "changes", "clearly", "c'mon", "co", "co.", "com", "come", "comes", "concerning", "consequently", "consider", "considering", "contain", "containing", "contains", "corresponding", "could", "couldn't", "course", "c's", "currently", "d", "dare", "daren't", "definitely", "described", "despite", "did", "didn't", "different", "directly", "do", "does", "doesn't", "doing", "done", "don't", "down", "downwards", "during", "e", "each", "edu", "eg", "eight", "eighty", "either", "else", "elsewhere", "end", "ending", "enough", "entirely", "especially", "et", "etc", "even", "ever", "evermore", "every", "everybody", "everyone", "everything", "everywhere", "ex", "exactly", "example", "except", "f", "fairly", "far", "farther", "few", "fewer", "fifth", "first", "five", "followed", "following", "follows", "for", "forever", "former", "formerly", "forth", "forward", "found", "four", "from", "further", "furthermore", "g", "get", "gets", "getting", "given", "gives", "go", "goes", "going", "gone", "got", "gotten", "greetings", "h", "had", "hadn't", "half", "happens", "hardly", "has", "hasn't", "have", "haven't", "having", "he", "he'd", "he'll", "hello", "help", "hence", "her", "here", "hereafter", "hereby", "herein", "here's", "hereupon", "hers", "herself", "he's", "hi", "him", "himself", "his", "hither", "hopefully", "how", "howbeit", "however", "hundred", "i", "i'd", "ie", "if", "ignored", "i'll", "i'm", "immediate", "in", "inasmuch", "inc", "inc.", "indeed", "indicate", "indicated", "indicates", "inner", "inside", "insofar", "instead", "into", "inward", "is", "isn't", "it", "it'd", "it'll", "its", "it's", "itself", "i've", "j", "just", "k", "keep", "keeps", "kept", "know", "known", "knows", "l", "last", "lately", "later", "latter", "latterly", "least", "less", "lest", "let", "let's", "like", "liked", "likely", "likewise", "little", "look", "looking", "looks", "low", "lower", "ltd", "m", "made", "mainly", "make", "makes", "many", "may", "maybe", "mayn't", "me", "mean", "meantime", "meanwhile", "merely", "might", "mightn't", "mine", "minus", "miss", "more", "moreover", "most", "mostly", "mr", "mrs", "much", "must", "mustn't", "my", "myself", "n", "name", "namely", "nd", "near", "nearly", "necessary", "need", "needn't", "needs", "neither", "never", "neverf", "neverless", "nevertheless", "new", "next", "nine", "ninety", "no", "nobody", "non", "none", "nonetheless", "noone", "no-one", "nor", "normally", "not", "nothing", "notwithstanding", "novel", "now", "nowhere", "o", "obviously", "of", "off", "often", "oh", "ok", "okay", "old", "on", "once", "one", "ones", "one's", "only", "onto", "opposite", "or", "other", "others", "otherwise", "ought", "oughtn't", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "outside", "over", "overall", "own", "p", "particular", "particularly", "past", "per", "perhaps", "placed", "please", "plus", "possible", "presumably", "probably", "provided", "provides", "q", "que", "quite", "qv", "r", "rather", "rd", "re", "really", "reasonably", "recent", "recently", "regarding", "regardless", "regards", "relatively", "respectively", "right", "round", "s", "said", "same", "saw", "say", "saying", "says", "second", "secondly", "see", "seeing", "seem", "seemed", "seeming", "seems", "seen", "self", "selves", "sensible", "sent", "serious", "seriously", "seven", "several", "shall", "shan't", "she", "she'd", "she'll", "she's", "should", "shouldn't", "since", "six", "so", "some", "somebody", "someday", "somehow", "someone", "something", "sometime", "sometimes", "somewhat", "somewhere", "soon", "sorry", "specified", "specify", "specifying", "still", "sub", "such", "sup", "sure", "t", "take", "taken", "taking", "tell", "tends", "th", "than", "thank", "thanks", "thanx", "that", "that'll", "thats", "that's", "that've", "the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "then", "thence", "there", "thereafter", "thereby", "there'd", "therefore", "therein", "there'll", "there're", "theres", "there's", "thereupon", "there've", "these", "they", "they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", "thing", "things", "think", "third", "thirty", "this", "thorough", "thoroughly", "those", "though", "three", "through", "throughout", "thru", "thus", "till", "to", "together", "too", "took", "toward", "towards", "tried", "tries", "truly", "try", "trying", "t's", "twice", "two", "u", "un", "under", "underneath", "undoing", "unfortunately", "unless", "unlike", "unlikely", "until", "unto", "up", "upon", "upwards", "us", "use", "used", "useful", "uses", "using", "usually", "v", "value", "various", "versus", "very", "via", "viz", "vs", "w", "want", "wants", "was", "wasn't", "way", "we", "we'd", "welcome", "well", "we'll", "went", "were", "we're", "weren't", "we've", "what", "whatever", "what'll", "what's", "what've", "when", "whence", "whenever", "where", "whereafter", "whereas", "whereby", "wherein", "where's", "whereupon", "wherever", "whether", "which", "whichever", "while", "whilst", "whither", "who", "who'd", "whoever", "whole", "who'll", "whom", "whomever", "who's", "whose", "why", "will", "willing", "wish", "with", "within", "without", "wonder", "won't", "would", "wouldn't", "x", "y", "yes", "yet", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "your", "you're", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves", "you've", "z", "zero");
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using the following code within my functions.php file to get the desired functionality:

```
// AUTOMATICALLY SANITIZE PAGE/POST SEO SLUG FROM SHORT WORDS
// SOURCE: http://www.vretoolbar.com/news/seo-slugs-wordpress-plugin
   add_filter('name_save_pre', 'seo_slugs', 0);
   function seo_slugs($slug) {
    // We don't want to change an existing slug
    if ($slug) return $slug;
    global $wpdb;
    $seo_slug = strtolower(stripslashes($_POST['post_title']));
    $seo_slug = preg_replace('/&.+?;/', '', $seo_slug); // kill HTML entities
    // kill anything that is not a letter, digit, space or apostrophe
    $seo_slug = preg_replace ("/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \']/", "", $seo_slug);
    // Turn it to an array and strip common words by comparing against c.w. array
    $seo_slug_array = array_diff (explode(" ", $seo_slug), seo_slugs_stop_words());
    // Turn the sanitized array into a string
    $seo_slug = join("-", $seo_slug_array);
    return $seo_slug;
   }
   function seo_slugs_stop_words () {
   return array ("a", "able", "about", "above", "abroad", "according", "accordingly", "across", "actually", "adj", "after", "afterwards", "again", "against", "ago", "ahead", "ain't", "all", "allow", "allows", "almost", "alone", "along", "alongside", "already", "also", "although", "always", "am", "amid", "amidst", "among", "amongst", "an", "and", "another", "any", "anybody", "anyhow", "anyone", "anything", "anyway", "anyways", "anywhere", "apart", "appear", "appreciate", "appropriate", "are", "aren't", "around", "as", "a's", "aside", "ask", "asking", "associated", "at", "available", "away", "awfully", "b", "back", "backward", "backwards", "be", "became", "because", "become", "becomes", "becoming", "been", "before", "beforehand", "begin", "behind", "being", "believe", "below", "beside", "besides", "best", "better", "between", "beyond", "both", "brief", "but", "by", "c", "came", "can", "cannot", "cant", "can't", "caption", "cause", "causes", "certain", "certainly", "changes", "clearly", "c'mon", "co", "co.", "com", "come", "comes", "concerning", "consequently", "consider", "considering", "contain", "containing", "contains", "corresponding", "could", "couldn't", "course", "c's", "currently", "d", "dare", "daren't", "definitely", "described", "despite", "did", "didn't", "different", "directly", "do", "does", "doesn't", "doing", "done", "don't", "down", "downwards", "during", "e", "each", "edu", "eg", "eight", "eighty", "either", "else", "elsewhere", "end", "ending", "enough", "entirely", "especially", "et", "etc", "even", "ever", "evermore", "every", "everybody", "everyone", "everything", "everywhere", "ex", "exactly", "example", "except", "f", "fairly", "far", "farther", "few", "fewer", "fifth", "first", "five", "followed", "following", "follows", "for", "forever", "former", "formerly", "forth", "forward", "found", "four", "from", "further", "furthermore", "g", "get", "gets", "getting", "given", "gives", "go", "goes", "going", "gone", "got", "gotten", "greetings", "h", "had", "hadn't", "half", "happens", "hardly", "has", "hasn't", "have", "haven't", "having", "he", "he'd", "he'll", "hello", "help", "hence", "her", "here", "hereafter", "hereby", "herein", "here's", "hereupon", "hers", "herself", "he's", "hi", "him", "himself", "his", "hither", "hopefully", "how", "howbeit", "however", "hundred", "i", "i'd", "ie", "if", "ignored", "i'll", "i'm", "immediate", "in", "inasmuch", "inc", "inc.", "indeed", "indicate", "indicated", "indicates", "inner", "inside", "insofar", "instead", "into", "inward", "is", "isn't", "it", "it'd", "it'll", "its", "it's", "itself", "i've", "j", "just", "k", "keep", "keeps", "kept", "know", "known", "knows", "l", "last", "lately", "later", "latter", "latterly", "least", "less", "lest", "let", "let's", "like", "liked", "likely", "likewise", "little", "look", "looking", "looks", "low", "lower", "ltd", "m", "made", "mainly", "make", "makes", "many", "may", "maybe", "mayn't", "me", "mean", "meantime", "meanwhile", "merely", "might", "mightn't", "mine", "minus", "miss", "more", "moreover", "most", "mostly", "mr", "mrs", "much", "must", "mustn't", "my", "myself", "n", "name", "namely", "nd", "near", "nearly", "necessary", "need", "needn't", "needs", "neither", "never", "neverf", "neverless", "nevertheless", "new", "next", "nine", "ninety", "no", "nobody", "non", "none", "nonetheless", "noone", "no-one", "nor", "normally", "not", "nothing", "notwithstanding", "novel", "now", "nowhere", "o", "obviously", "of", "off", "often", "oh", "ok", "okay", "old", "on", "once", "one", "ones", "one's", "only", "onto", "opposite", "or", "other", "others", "otherwise", "ought", "oughtn't", "our", "ours", "ourselves", "out", "outside", "over", "overall", "own", "p", "particular", "particularly", "past", "per", "perhaps", "placed", "please", "plus", "possible", "presumably", "probably", "provided", "provides", "q", "que", "quite", "qv", "r", "rather", "rd", "re", "really", "reasonably", "recent", "recently", "regarding", "regardless", "regards", "relatively", "respectively", "right", "round", "s", "said", "same", "saw", "say", "saying", "says", "second", "secondly", "see", "seeing", "seem", "seemed", "seeming", "seems", "seen", "self", "selves", "sensible", "sent", "serious", "seriously", "seven", "several", "shall", "shan't", "she", "she'd", "she'll", "she's", "should", "shouldn't", "since", "six", "so", "some", "somebody", "someday", "somehow", "someone", "something", "sometime", "sometimes", "somewhat", "somewhere", "soon", "sorry", "specified", "specify", "specifying", "still", "sub", "such", "sup", "sure", "t", "take", "taken", "taking", "tell", "tends", "th", "than", "thank", "thanks", "thanx", "that", "that'll", "thats", "that's", "that've", "the", "their", "theirs", "them", "themselves", "then", "thence", "there", "thereafter", "thereby", "there'd", "therefore", "therein", "there'll", "there're", "theres", "there's", "thereupon", "there've", "these", "they", "they'd", "they'll", "they're", "they've", "thing", "things", "think", "third", "thirty", "this", "thorough", "thoroughly", "those", "though", "three", "through", "throughout", "thru", "thus", "till", "to", "together", "too", "took", "toward", "towards", "tried", "tries", "truly", "try", "trying", "t's", "twice", "two", "u", "un", "under", "underneath", "undoing", "unfortunately", "unless", "unlike", "unlikely", "until", "unto", "up", "upon", "upwards", "us", "use", "used", "useful", "uses", "using", "usually", "v", "value", "various", "versus", "very", "via", "viz", "vs", "w", "want", "wants", "was", "wasn't", "way", "we", "we'd", "welcome", "well", "we'll", "went", "were", "we're", "weren't", "we've", "what", "whatever", "what'll", "what's", "what've", "when", "whence", "whenever", "where", "whereafter", "whereas", "whereby", "wherein", "where's", "whereupon", "wherever", "whether", "which", "whichever", "while", "whilst", "whither", "who", "who'd", "whoever", "whole", "who'll", "whom", "whomever", "who's", "whose", "why", "will", "willing", "wish", "with", "within", "without", "wonder", "won't", "would", "wouldn't", "x", "y", "yes", "yet", "you", "you'd", "you'll", "your", "you're", "yours", "yourself", "yourselves", "you've", "z", "zero");
   }
```

Also note that you NEED to have SLUG Metaboxes enabled for this to work. As I did not want the screen options or the actual metabox to show I added the following to an admin style sheet to remove them:

```
[for="slugdiv-hide"] { 
    display: none; 
    }

#slugdiv { 
    display: none; 
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is just a first idea: Check if it is the AJAX request.

```
if ( defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) 
    return $slug;
```

or:

```
if (
       isset( $_POST['action'] ) 
       && 'sample-permalink' === $_POST['action']
   ) return $slug;
```

depending on the level of detail you need.

If you put this in the beginning of the function (maybe below the first test `if ($slug) return $slug;` then the function should just quit.

If you still want to filter that input as well, for the AJAX request, you need to retrieve it from `$_POST['new_title']` instead of `$_POST['post_title']`. That's the reason why it deletes your input via AJAX editing.

Comment: thank you very much for you response. I tried both of the suggestions (copied and pasted the code directly below the if ($slug) return $slug; code but this did not have any result. I should also point out that without any modification I AM able to click on the URL text, change the slug name to whatever I want and press the "OK" botton which shows up... This does show the link correctly however when I click "update" post the data does not seem to be saved and it just reverts back to what it was before. Could you add the function to your site and see if you can get it to work correct?

Answer (score 0):

You should operate with `wp_ajax_sample-permalink` **action**  and `name_save_pre` **filter**.

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_sample-permalink', 'MyajaxSamplePermalink',0);     function MyajaxSamplePermalink($data) {
    $post_id = isset($_POST['post_id']) ? intval($_POST['post_id']) : 0;
    $post_name = isset($_POST['new_slug'])? $_POST['new_slug'] : null;
    $_POST['new_slug'] = YOUT_SLUG_MODIFY_FUNCTION($post_name);
}

add_filter('name_save_pre', 'filterNameSavePre');       function filterNameSavePre($post_name) {
    $post_id = isset($_POST['post_ID']) ? intval($_POST['post_ID']) : 0;
    $new_slug = isset($_POST['post_name']) ? $_POST['post_name'] : 0;
    $post_name = YOUT_SLUG_MODIFY_FUNCTION($new_slug);
    return $post_name;
}
```

and define your desired function

```
function YOUT_SLUG_MODIFY_FUNCTION($input){
      //........your codes.......
      return $input;
}
```