# custom slug always ends in "-2"

Tags: slug

I have a custom post type called task. I want the slug of each task to be an id, rather than use the entered title. I've modified the code from this SO question "[How to customize this automatic slug shortener with an overrwrite function](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1931/how-to-customize-this-automatic-slug-shortener-with-an-overrwrite-function)" as such:

```
add_filter('name_save_pre', array(__CLASS__, 'change_task_slug_to_id'));
static function change_task_slug_to_id($slug)
{
    // should prevent slug from being continually modified
    if ($slug) return $slug;
    return date('U');
}
```

However every time I add a new task, the slug is created with "-2" appended to it:
[image]

How can I prevent WordPress from re-modifying the slug, and appending the "-2"?

Answer (score 1):

Modification of a slug happens when wordpress detect that the slug is already in use. "In use" in this case includes the posts that are trashed. In your case if you don't need the id to be associated with the date then you might get better result by using the post id as the id, or implement some incremental counter.

Update: 
There was actually a ticket specific to numeric slugs https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5305. Should be fixed in 4.4

And it eems like there is a collusion detection with date (year) urls.

Comment: also if `tasks` are being created in a loop then there is a fair chance that at least two of them are going to have same value for `date('U')`

Comment: Thanks! I actually *want* the slug to be the post id, but had the same result, where "-2" was appended to the slug. So I settled for the date.

Per your answer - why is the slug "in use" when my code runs, thus appending "-2"?

I am using the WordPress admin editor, so 2 tasks are definitely not being created at the same time.

Comment: @Corey, In that case you obviously try to generate the slug more then once. It is really hard to guess why, but a safe way might be to check the actual slug of the post instead of the value being passed to the filter.

Comment: @MarkKaplun That's the problem. There is no post when it's first created. Seems like the slug is created, but the post is not.

Comment: @corey, if you still wonder about it, I have updated the answer